# test for convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Test for convergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^n}$$

I'm at a loss on what to do, is this a geometric series $\frac{1^n}{n^n}$?

Comment: No. But you can compare it nicely with a Geometric series to show it converges.

Comment: Does it converge to anything nice?? Just curious

Comment: @JackYoon http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n \leq \Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^2$$

Comment: I think you mean $\leq$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n>2$

$$\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n < \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

$|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \dfrac{1}{n+1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n} \to 0\cdot \dfrac{1}{e} = 0 < 1$ as $n \to \infty$, so the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\sqrt[n]{ \frac{1}{n^n}} =  \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and so the series converges.