# Is this going to converge? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{n}}$
is it converging, or diverging, what test do you use?

Comment: You can try to use the root test.

Comment: One thing that really helps when learning about infinite series, is to develop some kind of intuition for the behavior of the summand. Look at $n^n$. It grows absurdly quickly, in fact even faster than $n!$ (and hence $1/n^n$ tends towards zero very quickly). Once you gain a bit of intuition, you would be able to immediately see that it converges.

Comment: Some posts about the same question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773469/test-for-convergence-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nn
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861656/test-for-convergence-with-either-comparison-test-or-limit-comparison-test
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744833/determine-whether-or-not-the-following-series-is-convergent-sum-n-1-infty
Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E%7Bn%7D%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an nth term with a power in the denominator, we can *compare* this series to a p-series. We must, however, pick the correct p-series.

The p-series test states that:

If the nth term of the sequence of your series is of the form $\frac {1}{n^p}$, then,

for all $p\gt 1$, the series converges, and

for all $p\le1$, the series diverges.

Now we will use the direct comparison test, which states that:

If $0 \lt a_n \lt b_n$ for all n, then

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ diverges.

We know that $\frac{1}{n^n} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n\ge1$. You can easily test this by plugging in values for $n$ into both formulas. Thus, let $b_n = \frac {1}{n^2}$ and $a_n = \frac {1}{n^n}$.

By the p-series test, we know that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges: $p = 2 \gt 1$.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.

Thus, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^n}$ converges.

Hoorah! Finally, we conclude that because the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges by the p-series test, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^n}$ converges by the direct comparison test.

---

**Note:** I chose to compare $\frac{1}{n^n}$ to $\frac{1}{n^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n}$ for a good reason. First notice that $\frac {1}{n^n} \le \frac 1n$ for all $n \ge 1$, so $b_n = \frac 1n$ and $a_n =\frac {1}{n^n}$.  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is the harmonic series, and by the p-series test we know that this diverges. Here is the crucial part: $b_n$ diverges. We cannot deduce anything from the direct comparison test if $b_n$ diverges. Thus, I went with $\frac {1}{n^2}$ as $b_n$, instead. *This* converges by the p-series test, and now you see that we *can* deduce information from the direct comparison test if $b_n$ converges - namely, that $a_n$ will converge as well.

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{1}{n^n} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$ for $n\ge2$ so you can compare it with $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $n^n\ge n!>0$.

Since $n^n>0$, the sequence of partial sums, $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^n}$ monotonically increases.

Moreover, we see that

> $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^n}\right|\le \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n!}<e$$

Inasmuch as the sequence of partial sums is monotonically increasing and bounded above (by $e$ in fact), it converges.

---

Aside, the series is part of the [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) since it is equal to the integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^x}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}\approx 1.29129$$

---

We can obtain a crude upper bound for the series by noting that (see the [Integral Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence))

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}&\le 1+\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^x}\,dx\\\\
&=1+\int_0^1 e^{-x\log(x)}\,dx\\\\
&\le 2-\frac1e \\\\
&\approx 1.632120559
\end{align}$$

This upper bound has an error of roughly than $26$% with the actual value of the series.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality for $n\ge1$
$$
n^n\ge\left(n-\tfrac12\right)\left(n+\tfrac12\right)
$$
can be verified for $n=1$ and for $n\ge2$
$$
n^n\ge n^2\ge n^2-\tfrac14=\left(n-\tfrac12\right)\left(n+\tfrac12\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^n}
&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\left(n-\frac12\right)\left(n+\frac12\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1{n-\frac12}-\frac1{n+\frac12}\right]\\[6pt]
&=2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n^n}$.

Then

$$|a_n|^{1/n}=\frac{1}{n} \to 0<1.$$

The root-test shows that the series converges.